# How to run multiple java runtime jobs and wait for all of them to finish?

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, jobs

I have this code to run a job with a progress bar in java:

```
private void createNewJobRun(final int i) {
    Job job = new Job("Experiment " //$NON-NLS-1$
            + getName()) {
        @Override
        protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {

            monitor.beginTask("Experiment is running ...", 100); //$NON-NLS-1$
            //call here my own functions that to the actual work

            monitor.done();
            return Status.OK_STATUS;
        }
    };
    job.schedule();



}
```

The problem is that I want to call this function many times but only the first job runs and the others are almost simultaneously started but I never see their results...Although their progress monitor is shown. How do I wait for all of them to finish in some way or the problem is something else?

Comment: Are you starting them using threads or in a sequence?

Comment: This method is called in a loop like this: 
for (int i...)
 creteNewJobRun(i)
without any extra threading.

Comment: Does `Job` itself use threading internally or is it submitted to something like a thread pool? Can you show the `Job` class?

Comment: The Job class is not written by me :
org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.Job

Answer (score -1):

At First, you must make your own Class which is a subclass from Callable.

In this class you override the call method and do the things you do in createNewJobRun.

Now you must create a FutureTask (that is executed in a Thread to make your Job and get a result).

Example: Look at this link (at the heading FutureTask`<V>`)

[HERE](http://www.angelikalanger.com/Articles/EffectiveJava/19.Callables/19.Callables.html)